# unable to load asset $key, Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

mi codigo se detiene en la siguiente linea de codigo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo que me deberia cargar la imagen, ya se que la importe desde el navegador de mi celular o con la camara, en mi widget image:

```
_mostrarfoto()
  {
    if (producto.fotoUrl != null)
    {
      return Container();
    }
    else
    {
      return Image(
        image: AssetImage( foto?.path ?? 'assets/no-image.png'),
        height: 300,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      );
    }
  }
```

esta parte es para navegar en el celular y obtener la imagen:

```
  _seleccionarfoto() async
  {
    foto = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
      source: ImageSource.gallery,
    );

    if (foto!=null){

    }

    setState(() { });
  }
```

esta parte es para tomar con el celular una foto:

```
  _tomarfoto() async 
  {
    foto = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
      source: ImageSource.camera,
    );

    if (foto!=null)
    {

    }

    setState(() {

    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El `ImagePicker` te retorna un `File`, no puedes usar el file dentro de un `AssetImage` provider, ya que como su nombre lo dice solo recibe assets.

Tienes que usar el provider `FileImage`, entonces quedaría así:

```dart
return Image(
        image: foto?.path != null? FileImage(foto)  : AssetImage('assets/no-image.png'),
        height: 300,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      );
```

Comment: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/iKTw5dwQYOY/maxresdefault.jpg